# how to read data in c++ from a file stored in any other structure e-g: .text file

Tags: c++

i gotta read data in c++ from a text file stored in computer
and then tokenize the data on the basis of space so that each word becomes a separate string

i have tried a code but it doesn't print anything as an output instead of a black blank screen

```
 // basic file operations
 #include <iostream.h>
 #include <fstream.h>
 #include <conio.h>
 //using namespace std;

 int main ()
 {
       ofstream myfile;
       myfile.open ("example.txt");``
       myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    // myfile.close();`
       getch();
       return 0;
 }
```

please help :(

Comment: post what your file looks like

Comment: You want to read it in and use `ofstream`?

Comment: I think you need to try harder: this code clearly doesn't even attempt to _read_ anything!

Comment: Are you trying to read a file? `>>` to read... you have used `<<` which writes.

Comment: @doctorlove Also, `ifstream` for reads, `ofstream` for writes.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted does not attempt to write anything to standard output (`std::cout`).  It opens a file (example.txt) and writes "Writing this to a file" in it, closes the file, and then waits for you to press a button before exiting the program.  You are seeing no output because you've provided no output operations, nor does it attempt to read anything from the file.

Answer (score 1):

First use ifstream since you want this file as input not output

Second what is this code you posted has to do with the question?

Try this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("example.txt");
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        std::string str;
        while (std::getline(file, token, ' '))
        {
           //here str is your tokenized string 
        }

    } else
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file";
    }

}
```

getline will get the next string until the end of line or ' ' is met

Comment: He is including `conio.h` for `getch()` so that his console doesn't disappear as soon as the program ends (which is the default behavior).  It isn't being used for anything useful to the problem.

Comment: doesn't `cin >> something` does the same? since it waits for an input.

Comment: No, `getch()` returns as soon as you press a key.  `cin >> something` requires you to press enter.  `cin.get()` behaves in a closer fashion to `getch()`

Comment: Also, `istream`'s insertion operator (for `std::string`) stops on whitespace by default, so you can use `file >> str` instead of `getline(file, str, ' ' )`

Comment: Good to know, but what happens at the end of the line? it stops at \n too?

Comment: `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, etc. are whitespace and will be treated as a separator between valid inputs.

Answer (score 0):

This code WRITES to a file...maybe there's a C++ way to do it but strtok does what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Found within a minute of googling :)

```
using namespace std;
string STRING;
ifstream myReadFile;
myReadFile.open("Test.txt");
char output[100];
if (myReadFile.is_open())
{
    while (!myReadFile.eof())
    {
        getline(myReadFile,STRING);
        cout << STRING;
    }
    myReadFile.close();
}
```

Edit: Fixed the thing and tested it with success.

Comment: `while (!myReadFile.eof())` is wrong.  As is an uninitialized character buffer.